# Can a tty be made unkillable?

Tags: tty, kill, signals

I used PuTTY to ssh into a linux machine from a windows machine and I was just messing about with the `pkill` command. I quickly found out that I could log out of a remote session by typing `w` to show users and tty then `pkill -9 -t pts/tty-number` to log the session out.

But I was wondering, is there a way I could make the specific tty number unkillable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Since you own the processes on that tty, sending `kill -9` to them with pkill will cause them to "abnormally terminate" because that signal cannot be caught or ignored (see [signals.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html)).

You can set up signal handlers to ignore *other* signals, but not `-9`.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way
When im in school people start pkilling each other

Comment: If they have sudo or root, you're out of luck. Set up your own Linux VM and don't grant them access :)

Comment: is it possible for me to change my tty number? if so can i also hide from the `w` command?

Comment: Not really; if you wanted to try to save your environments against the simplistic "kill what shows up in the output of `w`", you try screen or tmux. But if they can kill your processes, it's a race to the bottom.

Comment: @LukeAnglebert The only technical solution is for each of you to have their own account. That's what accounts are for. The social solution is to make people behave.